# How to replace app in itunes connect, while waiting in review?

Tags: iphone, replace, app-store-connect

Currently i am working in iPhone app, I have successfully upload iPhone app in itunes connect, noe i got some error in that app and fixed now, then i tried to upload a new build in same binary, is it possible? How to replace app, while waiting for review in itunes connect? please help me

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is an option to Cancel the binary in iTunes. Select that and upload the new binary.
Open Itunes account.

Perform following steps

- Select Manage Your Applications
- Click on the application
- Click on View details
- Click on *Binary Details* under *Links*
- Select '**Reject Binary**' in the upper right corner

Comment: this is outdated since apple has changed the ui in itunes connect. There is no reject binary button or binnary details or Links

Answer (score 9):

The other answers are outdated since Apple changed the UI in iTunes Connect. This is how it works now:

1. You first must upload a new binary using xCode or Application Builder (having a greater build number otherwise you won't be able to upload)
2. A "remove app version" button will appear in itunes connect, in the app details page, it is pretty visible and emphasized, you can't miss it. This will not actually delete the app version... it will just reject your binary. Your app version with all the details will be preserved.
3. After you press that your app status will be "developer rejected". Select the newly uploaded build for the new app version and click save.
4. Now your app status will be "preparing for submission". Press submit for review.

Note that the steps are referring to the case when you are submitting a new app version of an app but I imagine the steps are very similar for the case of a new app.

Comment: if i want to submit new binary after 6 days in waiting for review,how many days do thye take to review the app.?

Comment: when you submit a new binary, you will be moved to the back of the waiting queue. So I would estimate at least another 6 days...

Comment: Would this process extend our app review time as if new build is uplaoded.

Comment: @Ishika your question was already answered in comments and in other answers... so again: YES

Answer (score 2):

Use the "Reject binary" button so you can upload a new one.  You'll go back to end of the approval queue.

Comment: You'll go back to end of the approval queue.<<Again from the beginning...or just if i uploaded new binary in  6days then will review the day after?

Answer (score 2):

After following Sahil's answer, your status will change to "Developer Rejected".  You will need to go into "View Details", click on "Ready to Upload Binary", and follow the steps.  This will change your status back to "Waiting for Upload" at which point you will be able to submit a new version.

Answer (score 1):

Just one slight correction, when you say "you can't miss it", you underestimated me :-) I've gone through App Store, Features, TestFlight and Activity, and see no button labeled "Remove App Version". In my list of builds, Build # 4 is Waiting for Review, but I want Apple to review Build 6. If I click on Build # 4 ... I have some info about it, but nothing that lets me delete.

Comment: Same for me. I found it. See answer below.

Answer (score 1):

1. click on Waiting for review
2. click on remove this version from the review. this action will ONLY remove the build, not the screenshot, description etc.. so no worries..
3. submit new build

Answer (score 0):

1) First you have to "Reject the Binary".
Now you can edit your App in itunes connect. But before that first upload your changed (new) code. You'll probably have to get a new build number for it.

2) Now comes the tricky part. You have to remove the connection between the App definition in iTunes connect and the binary. It did cost me 25 minutes before I found it where that can be done.

[image: location of the stop sign]

In the details of the App is the build information. When you move over the date, a small stop sign will appear. That is the one you are looking for. Press it and delete the binary from this version.

3) Now press SAVE (otherwise the new binary will not be listed).

4) By using the (+) you can add your new binary.

5) Submit for review again

Answer (score 0):

[image]

There is now an information banner in blue (see image above) that let's you know how to remove your app from review.

"You can still edit all information while your version is waiting for review. To submit a new build, you must remove this version from review."