# itunes connect replace binary when status is "waiting for review"

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad, app-store-connect

We found bug after we submit the binary for approval in itunes connect and we upload a new build but we can not figure out how to replace the new build in itunes connect. the status of the build active.

Any of you knows how can replace the binary is for a approval with the new version of the binary?

I found this : [How to replace app in itunes connect, while waiting in review?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605208/how-to-replace-app-in-itunes-connect-while-waiting-in-review)

But it seems to make reference to the old version of itunes connect.

Comment: Take a look here  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25799874/how-to-reject-binary-from-itunes-connect-after-redesign-12-09-2014/25800118?iemail=1&noredirect=1#25800118

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Create a new build with new version, say your app version is 1.0, you need a new build with 1.0.1 but keep the version same.
2. Submit the build from xCode and wait for sometime, it takes a while to show up in the iTunes connect
3. In your app detail page now you should be able to click Build and select the right build version

I think this is what i did when i had the same scenario. Hope it helps!

Comment: How to select a build (you mentioned at 3). I can not do it, it is unselectable

Comment: That's strange! Generally you should see a circular add button once build gets available. Wait for some more time if not i guess you can delete the build and upload again!

Comment: Thanks for your help. After waiting some more hours, this option became available and I could do it! :)

Comment: this is outdated to some extent since apple has changed the UI in itunes connect. But still, if you follow this you will manage. The only trick is that you have to upload a new binary first (with a greater build number) before the "remove build" button will show up in itunes connect. After you remove build the status of your app will be "developer rejected". But now you can select the new build and submit again

Comment: Hi, would it increase the time of review if update a new build to the build which is already in review?

Comment: this is a bit confusing.."new build with new version" and then.."keep the version same".

Answer (score 1):

- Create a new Archive with new Bundle version Short,String In Your Info.plist. Ex.1.1 After That And Yes Donot Change Your version keep it same as previous vesion.
- After That Upload Your Binary
- Your App Detail Page Go to build setting and Remove Old Binary And Choose new binary that you previosly uploaded..It may Be help you.

Comment: How to remove the old binary?

Answer (score 1):

You can't remove and replace the build anymore until you remove the app from review.

You go to your app detail page, under App Store, in app store connect, then at the top of the page there's a blue notification that indicates and confirms that in order to submit a new-build you must remove the version from review and gives you a link to click to do that.

Once you do, you can scroll down to builds and click the minus button on your build to remove it and then add a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to change the build number (from 1 to 2 for example) in the application info page (inside Xcode). The build number is enough (do not change the version ... I mean leave x.y as it was before). The build number would be enough to have a new entry in the list of builds in iTunes Connect. If you have already submitted the app, you have a button to cancel the review (if it's is not completed yet). Then resend the app for review (choosing by the list of available builds) and that's it.