# How to change third party content when app is in Waiting For Review?

Tags: ios, ios8, app-store-connect, itunes

I have submitted app and it is now in `Waiting For Review` but I by mistake check wrong third party content. How to change third party content when app is in  `Waiting For Review` ?
I was looking on iTunes connect on My Apps and cannot find any option to revoke from state `Waiting For Review` or change third party checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to "Reject Binary" in iTunesConnect. Then, you can re-upload and change the third party content status.

Comment: But that is a problem that there is no Reject Binary http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605208/how-to-replace-app-in-itunes-connect-while-waiting-in-review